# How to change SQL OFFSET value every iteration of a cron job

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am on a Wordpress site.  I am trying to automate the process of uploading a large amount of images to my server from another server.  My query is set to have a limit because my server will timeout with a 503 error if I try to add too many images.  I have a cron job to add images for the latest posts that are added which works with no issues.  I have tens of thousands of older posts with no images that need them.  I am wondering if there is any possible way to have my script run and then change the OFFSET after every iteration of it running on the cron.  For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID,l_key,post_title FROM `wp_term_relationships` INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON ID = object_id WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '906' AND post_type = 'listings' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";
```

My cron job is set to run every 15 minutes.  Is it possible for the OFFSET to increase by 5 every 15 min?

Comment: Any reason you don't have a bool on the table you're fetching from to say if the images have or haven't been sent? Also maybe add exponential backoff instead of failing on 500s

Comment: create one table in your database for temporary purpose. Store offset value there, and update that offset, every time a cron runs. Use the current offset value from the table, execute the cron, and increment the offset, so that next cron can use the increased offset

Comment: ohhhh I like that a lot.  Thats a good idea.  Thank you for the tip.